# Alternating series test proof, perhaps a mistake in Tao's proof I'm confused

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Definition:**
A sequence of real numbers is said to be  *eventually  $\epsilon$-steady* iff there exists an integer $N$ such that $|a_j - a_k| \leq \epsilon$ for all $j, k \geq N$.

In the last part of Tao's proof he writes:

> We have $S_N - a_{N+1} \leq S_n \leq S_N$ for all $n \geq N$. In
> particular, the sequence $S_n$ is eventually $a_{N+1}$-steady.

Here $S_N := \displaystyle \sum_{n=m}^{N} a_n$.

My question is how is this eventually $a_{N+1}$-steady? Clearly $S_N - a_{N+1} \leq S_n \leq S_N + a_{N+1}$ (since each $a_n$ is nonnegative).

Hence $|S_n - S_N| \leq a_{N+1}$ for all $n \geq N$. But we need $|S_n - S_j| \leq a_{N+1}$ for all $n,j \geq N$.

Comment: `$...$` is for math, not just for math *symbols*. So instead of $S_N$ $-$ $a_{N+1}$ $\leq$ $S_n$ $\leq$ $S_N$ `$S_N$ $-$ $a_{N+1}$ $\leq$ $S_n$ $\leq$ $S_N$` you can just type all the maths inside one like this: $S_N - a_{N+1} \leq S_n \leq S_N$ `$S_N - a_{N+1} \leq S_n \leq S_N$`. To learn how to type in MathJax, you can get started [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33179/80734); a more complete reference can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ and take $N\gg1$ such that $2a_{N+1}\le\epsilon$. Then we write what we already know twice:
$$ |S_n - S_N|\leq a_{N+1} \text{ for all }n\ge N$$
$$ |S_j - S_N|\leq a_{N+1} \text{ for all }j\ge N$$
Triangle inequality thus gives for any $n,j\ge N$
$$ |S_n - S_j|\le |S_n - S_N|+|S_j - S_N|\le 2a_{N+1} \le \epsilon$$
which is what we wanted.

Well, OK, what we did proved that $S_n$ is eventually $\epsilon$-steady for all $\epsilon>0$. But now you can take $\epsilon=a_{N+1}$. Perhaps a little roundabout...

Comment: Ah okay thanks for this, but then what was the point in writing: We have $S_N$ $-$ $a_{N+1}$ $\leq$ $S_n$ $\leq$ $S_N$ for all $n$ $\geq$ $N$ 
in particular, the sequence $S_n$ is eventually $a_{N+1}$-$steady$

Comment: I'm not entirely sure and perhaps I will agree more with how Tao wrote it on a different day. But the important thing is to understand one way to get to the conclusion @JCAL

Comment: Yes thank you very much for this!

Answer (score 2):

We now that $S_N - a_{N+1} \leq S_n,S_m \leq S_N$ for all $n,m\geq N$. Assume $S_n\leq S_m$. Then $0\leq S_m-S_n\leq S_N-(S_N- a_{N+1})=a_{N+1}$. Thus $\vert S_m-S_n\vert \leq a_{N+1}$. This is also true in the case $S_m\leq S_n$.